# Displaying Points in Scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

Currently trying to write a simple r script that when passed in 2 vectors of values would calculate some relationship between them (in the given case, r_square) and display it in a graph with the best fit line.

```
temp1 <- sample(20000,1367,replace=F,prob=NULL)
temp2 <- sample(20000,1367,replace=F,prob=NULL)
fit <- lm(temp1 ~temp2)
plot(temp1,temp2,ann="true")
abline(fit)
```

(here using sample in lack of real data).
The problem is that i'm trying to add interactivity which would display point's value (X/Y coordinates of sort) on hover.

I've managed to find a few functions that identify them by the their order in the vectors (HWidentify, identify, etc). But none of them give the actual value (x,y) so i was wondering if it's possible to print out coordinates that aren't permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to print the coordinates, you could use the `labels` argument to the `identify()` function.

```
identify(temp1, temp2, labels=paste(temp1, temp2, sep=","))
```

Comment: Thanks, just got it while messing around (i wish there was more documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The `HWidentify` function also has a labels argument that you can set to whatever you want, using the `paste` function like @JeanV.Adams works similarly and then you have the hover functionability.